# Error in Laravel helper in fresh installation

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have installed fresh laravel-5.5 installation but it is showing parse error.

`unexpected ? in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 233`

I am using WAMP with php version 7.2.4

Previously it was 5.8 which I changed to 7.2.4.
restarted the WAMP and reinstalled the new porject.

It still gives me the same error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbZw5.png)